# A combinatorial property of uncountable groups, II

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, ramsey-theory

> **Problem 1.** Is it true that each uncountable group $G$ contains two subsets $A,B\subset G$ such that
>
> 1) for any $x,y\in G$ the intersection $xA\cap yB$ is finite and
>
> 2) for any function $\Phi:G\to 2^G$ assigning to each element $g\in G$ a finite subset $\Phi(g)\subset G$ there are two elements $x,y\in G$ and points $a\in A\setminus\Phi(x)$ and $b\in B\setminus \Phi(y)$ such that $xa=yb$.

**Remark.** Such sets $A,B$ do exist if $G$ contains a subgroup $H$ that admits a homomorphism onto a group $\Gamma$ that contains an uncountable subset $U$ with infinite centralizer $C(U)=\bigcap_{u\in U}\{x\in\Gamma:xu=ux\}$. This means that a counterexample if exists, should be very non-commutative, like a Jonsson group, constructed by [Shelah](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0049237X08713466).
We recall that a group $G$ is *Jonsson* if it is uncountable but all proper subgroups of $G$ are countable.

> **Problem 2.** What is the answer to the Problem for simple Jonsson groups (constructed by [Shelah](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0049237X08713466))?

**Comment.** Problem 1 is a combinatorial reformulation of Question 2.2 from [this survey of Protasov](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.03028.pdf). Question 2.2 asks if the countability of a group is equivalent to the normality of its finitary ballean. This question was also repeated (as Problem 12.6) in the paper ["The normality and bounded growth of balleans"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.07979) of Banakh and Protasov.

Comment: Say that $(A,B)$ is a good pair in $G$. So if I understand correctly, there's no good pair if $G$ is countable. Is there an immediate way to see that if $(A,B)$ is a good pair then both $A,B$ are uncountable?

Comment: Basic remark: if $G\subset H$ and $G$ has a good pair then so does $H$. As mentioned in Protasov, uncountable free groups and uncountable abelian groups admit good pairs. So a group without good pair has no uncountable abelian or free subgroup.

Comment: @YCor If $(A,B)$ is a good pair, then we only can assert that one of the sets $A$ or $B$ is uncountable. Moreover, for a countable group $A$ and an uncountable group $B$ the pair $(A,B)$ is good in the group $G=A\oplus B$.

Comment: There's no "**the** Jonsson group constructed by Shelah", as Shelah makes high use of the the axiom of choice and those various choices most likely produce many non-isomorphic Jonsson groups.

Comment: @YCor You are right. Thanks. I made the corresponding corrections in the formulations.

Comment: The commutative argument shows that if $G$ has no good pair, then the centralizer of any infinite subset of $G$ is countable (or, equivalently: the centralizer of any uncountable subset of $G$ is finite). Indeed start from a of subgroups $(A,B)$ with $A$ infinite, $B$ uncountable, $[A,B]=1$. If $A/(A\cap B)$ is infinite, choose $A'\subset A$ set of representatives modulo $A\cap B$, then $(A',B)$ is a good pair. Otherwise $A\cap B$ is infinite; choose $B'\subset B$ a set of representatives modulo $A\cap B$, and then $(A\cap B,B')$ is a good pair.

Comment: Also I think that a Jonsson group means an uncountable group all of whose proper subgroups have smaller cardinal, or equivalently such that all subsets of maximal cardinality are generating subsets. So your definition corresponds to ``Jonsson group of cardinal $\aleph_1$".

Comment: To extend the remark about quotients: if $G$ has a quotient $Q$, and $(A,B)$ is a good pair in $Q$, $A'$, is a lift of $A$ and $B''$ is the inverse image of $B$, then $(A',B'')$ is a good pair in $G$. That is, the set of groups with no good pairs is stable under taking quotients. (In addition to stable under taking subgroups, and to imply the condition on centralizers.)

Comment: @YCor In fact, groups without good pairs are exactly groups with normal finitary ball structure. Let us all such groups are normal. So, the normality is preserved by taking subgroups and quotient groups. An uncountable group which is a direct product  of infinite groups is not normal.

Comment: I'm aware of this fact (that no good pairs means with NFBS). I used the language introduced in this post only, so don't refer to NFBS.

Comment: @YCor Today I have posted a paper devoted to nomality of balleans to arxiv. It will appear tomorrow (I hope). It contains all known facts I know about the normality of balleans (on groups).

Comment: Problem 2 has a negative answer: any center-free $\aleph_1$-Jonsson group (i.e. of cardinal $\aleph_1$) is a counterexample. (It is not hard to check that any $\aleph_1$-Jonsson group has a centerfree $\aleph_1$-Jonsson quotient.)

Comment: @YCor Thank you for your solution to Problem 2. So, I will delete this problem from my post as being solved.

Comment: I don't either have it (I once had a hard copy).

Comment: @TarasBanakh The following two comments may be relevant: (1) If $G$ is an infinite non-abelian group then $G$ contains infinite subsets $X$ and $Y$ such that $XY\cap YX=\varnothing$. (2) If $a$ is a non-central element of an infinite group $G$, then there exists an infinite subset $X$ of $G$ such that $aX\cap Xa=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems 1 and 2 both have affirmative answers (implying that the finitary ballean of any uncountable group is normal).

Two cases are possible:

I. There exists a countable subgroup $A\subset G$ and an uncountable subset $B\subset G$ such that $bAb^{-1}\cap A$ is infinite for all $b\in B$. Replacing $B$ by a smaller uncountable set, we can assume that the family $(bA)_{b\in B}$ is disjoint. The latter condition can be used to show that the sets $A,B$ satisfy the condition 1 of the Problem.

We claim that for any function $\Phi:G\to [G]^{<\omega}$ there are elements $x,y\in G$ and $a\in A\setminus\Phi(x)$ and $b\in B\setminus \Phi(y)$ such that $xa=yb$.
Since $B$ is uncountable, there exists an element $b\in B\setminus\bigcup_{a\in H}\Phi(a)$. The set $bAb^{-1}\cap A$ is infinite and hence contains some element $a\notin\Phi(b)$. Put $x=b$ and $y=bab^{-1}\in A$. Observe that $xa=ba=yb$, $a\notin\Phi(b)=\Phi(x)$ and $b\notin\Phi(y)$.

II. There exists a countable infinite subgroup $A\subset G$ and an uncountable set $B'\subset G$ such that $bAb^{-1}\cap A$ is finite for every $b\in B'$. Replacing $B'$ by a smaller uncountable subset, we can aditionally assume that the family $(AbA)_{b\in B'}$ is disjoint.

We claim that the sets $A$ and $B=\{aba^{-1}:a\in A,\;b\in B'\}$ satisfy the conditions 1 and 2. The condition 1 will follow as soon as we check that for every $x\in G$ the intersection $xA\cap B$ is finite. Assuming that this intersection is not empty, we can find  elemente $b\in B'$ and $a,\alpha\in A$ such that $x\alpha=aba^{-1}$. Taking into account that the family $(AvA)_{v\in B}$ is disjoint, we conclude that $xA\cap B=abA\cap B\subset abA\cap b^A$ where $b^A=\{gbg:g\in A\}$.

Given any element $z\in abA\cap b^A$, we can find elements $\alpha,g\in A$ with $ab\alpha=z=gbg^{-1}$ and conclude that $a^{-1}g=b\alpha gb^{-1}\in A\cap bAb^{-1}$. So, the element $g$ belongs to the finite set $F=a(A\cap gAg^{-1})$ and then $z=gbg^{-1}\in b^F:=\{fbf^{-1}:f\in F\}$. Therefore, $xA\cap B=abA\cap b^A$ is contained in the finite set $b^F$, which means that the sets $A,B$ satisfy the condition 1.

Now given any function $\Phi:G\to [G]^{<\omega}$, we shall find elements $x,y\in G$ and $a\in A\setminus\Phi(x)$ and $b\in B\setminus \Phi(y)$ such that $xa=yb$.

Using the uncountability of the set $B'$, choose an element $u\in B'\setminus \bigcup_{a\in A}a\Phi(a)a^{-1}$. 
Find $a\in A\setminus \Phi(u)$. Put $y=a\in A$, $x=u$ and $b=a^{-1}ua\in B$. It follows that $xa=ua=aa^{-1}ua=yb$.
Also $a\notin\Phi(u)=\Phi(x)$ and $b=a^{-1}ua\notin \Phi(a)$ (as $u\notin a\Phi(a)a^{-1}$).